# Windows CE web browser blank page

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, windows-ce

I've created a simple HTML page to be opened into a webBrowser control into a Vb .Net application on a Windows CE 7 pocket PC.
The pocket PC doesn't have internet explorer installed, so when i open the HTML page with the following code:

**Me.WebBrowser.Navigate(New Uri(*HTML file path*))**

the webBrowser will be show blank page.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Hello, if you have not IE installed this is definitely your problem. But I'm confused by the following sentence when you say that the browser is opening a blank page. Did you mean that what you get is a white screen right? Did you log any exception thrown?

Comment: The WebBrowser control doesn't give me any exception when i do Navigate function just it remains blank and, so, it doesn't show me the htm page.

Comment: Ok, you just need a WinCE image with IE installed. Can you make your own image for your target device?